# Does code of CUDA kernel-function upload to the GPU-RAM at once or for each call to it?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Does the executable code of CUDA kernel function upload to the GPU at once when starting program, or does the code upload each time a kernel function is called? Or in which cases may be one way or the other?

This can greatly influence the choice of programming methods:

- A lot of calls to kernel-function from CPU-host
- The use of dynamic parallelism and a lot of calls to kernel-functions from GPU-device

Comment: The main overhead in launching a kernel is due to copying the kernel code itself to the GPU as well as copying the arguments. I think this is done each time the kernel is launched.

Comment: @JackOLantern: can you cite a reference to support  the first part of your comment?

Comment: @talonmies PGI User Forum, [kernel launch overhead](http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=2906&sid=dddfdae3c885e735f26c98129e7bc064) post.

Comment: Copying the kernel code to the GPU only has to be done once.  Originally, it was done at module load time (for CUDA runtime apps, during the deferred initialization for a given GPU), but NVIDIA may have revisited that heuristic since.  For example, they may load the microcode on first invocation of a given kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the CUDA runtime API, kernel code is downloaded to the device once. This happens as an implicit action right after CUDA runtime context creation. When using the CUDA driver API, the app has control over when kernels get downloaded, and how often. It seems this is not currently covered by the CUDA documentation, I will file an enhancement request for that.

Comment: Thanks! But why does each launch of small kernel-function take so much time - about 30 microseconds?

Comment: And does each launch of small kernel-function from the other kernel-function by using dynamic parallelism takes the same much time?

Comment: A launch of an empty kernel should take about 3-5 microseconds. That's what I am seeing with various GPUs on Linux and WinXP. You may see different timing (longer times) if you are on Windows {Vista|7|8} and using the WDDM driver, which uses batching to mitigate the high overhead inherent in that driver model. I haven't personally used dynamic parallelism. Asking separate questions in a separate thread is a better fit for Stackoverflow's Q&A format. That gives other people a chance to answer based on their expertise, and makes questions [and answers!] easy to find.

Comment: Ok. Yes I use Win7 and it take about 30 microseconds.

Comment: Alex, if you do one kernel launch under WDDM and then force the work to be submitted (e.g. by calling cudaDeviceSynchronize()), the overhead of the user->kernel transition will be much higher.  If you do several kernel launches before causing the work to be submitted, CUDA will only do one kernel thunk and the overhead per kernel launch will be lower.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware Yes I must call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` to synchronize with `cudaMemcpy()`

Comment: cudaMemcpy() is synchronous, so will force submission of pending work.